# Unix scripting: accessing required .ear file by filename mask

Tags: java, unix, scripting, ksh

Task: need to unzip ear archive and access MANIFEST file to grep Build-version string value. Current script looks like this:

```
  MESSAGE=`unzip -o -d $APPBIN $APP/Engine_LIVE_1.1.0.1.ear META-INF/MANIFEST.MF >> /dev/null && cat $APPBIN/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF | grep Build-Version && rm -rf $APPBIN/META-INF`
```

As you can see, changing of ear version causes filename changes and script fails.

Is it possible to make this script command independable from version number? Is it possible to use some kind of regular expressions or file mask? I know that there is only one .ear file in $APP folder and its name starts from Engine_LIVE_ string.

Comment: You're welcome. I'd modify it a bit like this: `Engine_LIVE_*.ear`.

Comment: Actually, we took into account possible situation with a lot of *.ear files and now we use iteration through array of files

Answer (score 0):

Solved. 
Need to use Engine_LIVE_*